# How can i remove/delete digits in the beginning of a string?

Tags: c#, .net

The problem is that in tn.Text the string start with a number and a dot/point for example:

1. hello
2. hi
3. world

And i need that tn.Text will contain only the text for example:

```
hello
hi
world
```

This is the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    public partial class DisplayResponses : Form
    {        
        private List<string> nodesNames = new List<string>();
        private List<TreeNode> CurrentNodeMatches = new List<TreeNode>();

        public DisplayResponses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            addmore();
        }

        public void addmore()
        {
            foreach (List<string> l_branch in ListsExtractions.responsers)
            {
                TreeNode l_node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_branch.Count - 1]);

                for (int l_count = 0; l_count < l_branch.Count - 1; l_count++)
                {
                    l_node.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_count]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisplayResponses_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtParentName.Text = "";
                txtText.Text = "";
                txtTag.Text = "";

                if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name != null)
                {
                    txtName.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString();
                }
                if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text != null)
                {
                    txtText.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();
                }
                if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag != null)
                {
                    txtTag.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString();
                }
                if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent != null)
                {
                    txtParentName.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearBackColor();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearBackColor();
            try
            {
                TreeNode[] tn = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Find(txtNodeSearch.Text, true);
                for (int i = 0; i < tn.Length; i++)
                {
                    treeView1.SelectedNode = tn[i];
                    treeView1.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void ClearBackColor()
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {
                ClearRecursive(n);
            }
        }

        private void ClearRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                tn.BackColor = Color.White;
                ClearRecursive(tn);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearBackColor();
            FindByText();
        }

        private void FindByText()
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {
                FindRecursive(n);
            }
        }

        private void FindRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                int index = tn.Text.IndexOf(" ");
                string text = tn.Text.Substring(0, index);
                tn.Text = tn.Text.Replace(text, "").TrimStart();
                if (tn.Text == this.txtNodeTextSearch.Text)
                    tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                FindRecursive(tn);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearBackColor();
            FindByTag();
        }

        private void FindByTag()
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {
                FindRecursiveTag(n);
            }
        }

        private void FindRecursiveTag(TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                if (tn.Tag.ToString() == this.txtTagSearch.Text)
                    tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                FindRecursiveTag(tn);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Edit:

Found a way to do it but it's very slow make everything freeze hang on too long:

```
private void FindRecursive(TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                int index = tn.Text.IndexOf(" ");
                string text = tn.Text.Substring(0, index);
                tn.Text = tn.Text.Replace(text, "").TrimStart();
                if (tn.Text == this.txtNodeTextSearch.Text)
                    tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                FindRecursive(tn);
            }
        }
```

If in tn.Text for example i have: 4. hello
And i type in textBox2 hello and click the button it will take forever.

But if i remove this code:

```
int index = tn.Text.IndexOf(" ");
string text = tn.Text.Substring(0, index);
tn.Text = tn.Text.Replace(text, "").TrimStart();
```

Then it's working fast but i need to type 4. hello
And not only hello

Why it's so slow when adding this part of code with the IndexOf and Substring ?

Comment: How about `Substring` if the format is consistent?

Comment: What does this code have to do with anything? Have you tried anything so far? Without any (relevant) code shown, it sounds like you're asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Is the format always consistent. Does each line always begin with x._ where x is a number and _ is a space?

Comment: Smith.h.Neil yes. all the time it's x.space

Comment: Edited my question added the class code the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the last character of the prefix (in the above example this would be the space between the period and the first character of the text you want), then use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) to cut out the part that you want.

You may be better off using the single-argument form of Substring described as "The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string." If the position you passed it were one past the space you found then the Substring method should return the part you want, and it may speed it compared to the other form, because you can then remove the TrimStart and Replace method calls.

Comment: Thank you for not spoon feeding a complete solution!

Comment: Updated my question after using IndexOf and Substring. If i use breakpoint i see it's removing the digits as i wanted. But when i let it keep working it's too slow forever. If i'm not using this part of code with the IndexOf and Substring it's working fast but then i need to type in the textBox2 text changed event also the digits like: 4. hello and i want that i will be able to type only hello

Comment: I've updated my answer to match, hope it helps!  I'm not sure I follow the second part of the question though, could you reword it for me?  Sorry!

Comment: Timothy only this question: Why it's so slow when adding this part of code with the IndexOf and Substring ?

Comment: For every string in the list it's going to have to search for the first space, then cut up the string accordingly, which will of course imply slightly more overhead.  That said, if you're still using the code in the question text it's far from optimized.  You can just use substring to get the second half, then you won't need the Replace or TrimStart method calls, and TrimStart is, from what I understand, not particularly well-optimized.

Answer (score 1):

TrimStart was made for this:

```
TrimStart(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ' ', });
```